# Server sent event on Angular makes multiple call

Tags: java, angular, spring, server-sent-events

I am developing a simple chat system with Angular and Spring Boot using Sent Event Servers.

I have implemented the client, and it correctly receives events. But when I analysed the browser network console, I noticed a strange behaviour.
I was expecting to find a single call to my endpoint, sse I found multiple calls.

I will investigate in more detail and add an event on the onopen. I confirmed that multiple calls are being made.

Does anyone know if I am doing something wrong or is this normal Angular behaviour?
Below is the client code and screenshot of the network

```
  private getMessages(): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable((observer: { next: (arg0: any) => void; }) => {
      let ess = new EventSource("http://localhost:8080/api/messages");

      ess.onopen = ev => {
        console.log("Connection open")
      }

      ess.onmessage = ev => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
          observer.next(ev.data)
        })
      }
    })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sub = this.getMessages().subscribe({
      next: (data: any) => {
        //console.log(data);
        this.addMessage(data)
      },
      error: err => console.log(err)
    });
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Are you unsubscribing on component destroy?

Comment: The problem also occurs when first creating the component without subsequently browsing.
The onDestroy would not be called at the point where I am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution; the problem was due to the backend part.

Specifically, to implement the SSE on the backend side, I used l-object Flux, but I created it in the following way.

```
Flux.fromIterable(messages)
```

This makes that when the messages are finished, the socket will be closed; the solution was to modify the Flux as follows,

```
Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
```

In this way, the socket always stays open.